# How to free a struct with a function pointer member?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I am allocating a struct with a function pointer. Obviously, I have to free the struct at the program end. However, freeing a function pointer leads to undefined behavior. How should I do it? I tried to create a pointer to this pointer to a function point but it does not work, right? Attached a minimal example.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int le_double(void *a, void *b){return *(double *)a < *(double *)b;}
 
typedef struct example
{
   double* data;  
   int (*le_fun)(void *, void *);
} Example;

Example* ExampleNew(int nItems)
{
   int size = sizeof(Example) + nItems * sizeof(double);
   Example* e =  malloc(size);
   e->data = (double *) (e + 1);
   e->le_fun = le_double;
   return e;
}
 
void test(int nItems)
{
   Example* e = ExampleNew(nItems);
   free(e);
}

int main()
{
   int nItems = 5;
   test(nItems);
}
```

Comment: Only `free` what you `malloc`.

Comment: why do you think you have to free the function pointer? btw you cannot free a pointer. you can only free what it points to. do you want to free the function le_double?

Comment: @dbush, I do not follow. In your opinion, the code is correct?

Comment: @user253751, I do not want to free the function. Does not free tries to free the function anyway?

Comment: You didn't allocate the value assigned to the function pointer, so you don't need to free it.

Comment: if you didn't malloc the function, then you can't free the function.

Comment: @dbush I have a program in c, I call from python. It started to fail with "Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6:SIGABRT)" after I added this pointer. It does not fail after the first call. It runs several times and then fails. I was sure it is related to the function pointer. Am I wrong?

Comment: The code as posted is fine.  You should post a minimal version of the code that *doesn't* work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You allocated one block of memory, and you freed that block of memory. That's all there is to do.

We say we free a pointer, but that's just a shorthand. We actually free that to which the pointer points. `e->le_fun` points to a function. You never allocated the memory used by the function, so you are not responsible for freeing it. It would be incorrect to call `free( e->le_fun )`.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to do anything.

The function pointer is just a value kept inside the structure, so it's freed when you `free()` the allocation.